# messages from firebase rtdb in list duplicate every time I enter Chatscreen swiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

every time I enter ChatScreen() messages duplicate with log `ForEach<Array<Message>, String, MessageView>: the ID //messageID occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!`

```
struct ChatScreen: View {
    @State private var message = ""
    var groupId: String
    var userId: String
    var userName: String
    @ObservedObject private var chatViewModel = ChatViewModel()
    
    
    init(groupId: String, userId: String, userName: String) {
        self.groupId = groupId
        self.userId = userId
        self.userName = userName
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView{
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(chatViewModel.messages, id: \.messageId) { message in
                        MessageView(message: message)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .onAppear {
                chatViewModel.observeMessages(groupId: groupId)
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Type your message here", text: $message)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                
                Button("Send") {
                    chatViewModel.sendMessage(messageText: message, userId: userId, groupId: groupId, userName: userName)
                    message = ""
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my message observer function:

```
func observeMessages(groupId: String) {
    let messagesRef = databaseRef.child("groups/\(groupId)/messages")
    messagesRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot, error in
        let message = Message(snapshot: snapshot)
        self.messages.append(message)
    }
}
```

messages duplicate only in device (not in database), after restarting the app, duplicate messages go away but every time I come back to groups list screen and then the ChatScreen, the messages duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear `self.messages` every time you get a new batch of messages:

So something like:

```
func observeMessages(groupId: String) {
    let messagesRef = databaseRef.child("groups/\(groupId)/messages")
    messagesRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot, error in
        let message = Message(snapshot: snapshot)
        self.messages.append(message)
    }
    messagesRef.observe(.value) { snapshot, error in
        self.messages.removeAll()
    }
}
```

Also see:

- [Duplicate Data from Firebase when I use .value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512632/duplicate-data-from-firebase-when-i-use-value)